# How to instantiate child actors when their constructor args are dependency injected?

Tags: playframework, akka, playframework-2.4

I am using Playframework and I am new to the Akka world. I am trying to create a child actor from a parent actor. The child actor depends on a service that is injected via guice. I am unable to figure out how to instantiate this child actor.

```
    class ParentActor extends UntypedActor{

        public static Props props = Props.create(ParentActor.class);

        @Override
        public void preStart() throws Exception{
          // The call here fails. I don't know how i should be creating the child actor 
          childActor = getContext().actorOf(childActor.props);
          childActor.tell(Protocol.RUN, self());
        }

        public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {
           if (msg == AggregateProtocol.DONE){
              sender().tell(Protocol.RUN, self());
           }
        } 

    }

    class ChildActor extends UntypedActor{

       private ServiceA serviceA;

       public static Props props = Props.create(ChildActor.class);

       @Inject
       public ChildActor(ServiceA serviceA){
           this.serviceA = serviceA
       }

        public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {
           if (msg == Protocol.RUN){
              serviceA.doWork();
              sender().tell(Protocol.DONE, self());
           }
        } 

   }
```

NOTE: I have also tried the methods using the factories and assisted inject as mentioned in Play Java akka documentation.

How do i get this thing to work ? I have looked at IndirectProducer and Creator methods too, but I was not able understand the documentation well.

Comment: Play has a comprehensive documentation about how to use dependency injection with actors: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaAkka#Dependency-injecting-actors

Answer (score 1):

You could inject the service into the parent actor and pass it on to every child.

Only the parent actor uses Guice dependency injection:

```
class ParentActor extends UntypedActor{

    private ServiceA serviceA;

    @Inject
    public ParentActor(ServiceA serviceA) {
      this.serviceA = serviceA;
    }

    @Override
    public void preStart() throws Exception{
      // Here pass the reference to serviceA to the child actor
      childActor = Akka.system().actorOf(ChildActor.props(serviceA);
      childActor.tell(Protocol.RUN, self());
    }

    public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {
       if (msg == AggregateProtocol.DONE){
          sender().tell(Protocol.RUN, self());
       }
    } 

}
```

And the child actor is created like always with props method.

```
class ChildActor extends UntypedActor{

   private ServiceA serviceA;

   public static Props props(ServiceA serviceA) {
     return Props.create(ChildActor.class, serviceA);
   }

   // No inject here
   public ChildActor(ServiceA serviceA){
       this.serviceA = serviceA
   }

   public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {
      if (msg == Protocol.RUN){
          serviceA.doWork();
          sender().tell(Protocol.DONE, self());
      }
   } 

}
```

There might be a better way with direct dependency injection into the child actor.

Comment: Thank you Kris. I Have tried your approach and it works. But I don't think this would be ideal when a deeply nested hierarchy of actors are involved.

Comment: I aggree. A direct injection would be better.